# DataframeSource reading from text file with multiline documents

Tags: r, tm

Hi I'm trying to use the tm package in R to create a Corpus from a CSV file of documents. From reading the documentation, I understand that DataframeSource expects two columns: 1) a unique identifier and 2) text. Each row should be a new document.

```
doc_id text
1      Document 1
2      Document 2
```

I have a sourcedata file with many documents that all span multiple lines.

```
doc_id text
1      Document 1
1      Document 1 continued
2      Document 2
2      Document 2 continued
```

Is there a quick and tidy way to read in everything with the same identifier as the same document? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you leverage `group_by` and `paste` to get the characters into a single field? An approach using dplyr:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(doc_id = as.character(c(1,1,2,2)), text_old = c('text 1', 'text 1 
        cont.','text 2', 'text 2 cont.'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

x <- data %>% 
  group_by(doc_id) %>% 
  mutate(text = paste(text_old, collapse = ",")) %>% 
  select(doc_id, text) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  DataframeSource()

x <- Corpus(x)

inspect(x)

<<SimpleCorpus>>
Metadata:  corpus specific: 1, document level (indexed): 0
Content:  documents: 2

                  1                   2 
 text 1,text 1 cont. text 2,text 2 cont.
```